# Cannot ask question?

Tags: support, bug, asking-questions

When I try to post a question with the "Ask question" button, it redirects to page "How to Ask" and the script doesn't show button "proceed" any more. I don't get any messages. Why does this happen? Is my account blocked?

[image]

Comment: S.L. Barth it link not help in my case. I not  get any of this messages
We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.    or We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: So what do you see? Could you post a screenshot of what you see after clicking "Ask Question"?

Comment: I can see button "proceed" .  And want to know what is it happen.  Is account problem or technical level problem met be with browser.

Comment: Without more information it's hard to say.

Comment: I added screen short for clarity.

Comment: Is there no "continue" button in the page you made a screen shot of?

Comment: Pekka 웃 "continue" button  you  mean  "proceed "  button? How I mention  in post   it not have "proceed "  button.    Your can see it on screen Shot  left bottom conner is empty.

Comment: What happens when you type `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` to the address bar instead of clicking "Ask Question"?

Comment: What browser? Any ad or script blockers running?

Comment: dorukayhan  ) it OK from this url all work in the normal way.  But if I tray make it from url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice? don't work. Seems it no actual for me anymore I can post now from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. Thanks   dorukayhan                                                                                       jonrsharpe   Safary Version 9.1.3  but I posted question with it version before and now on https://meta.stackoverflow.com . For me only  url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?  is broken.

Comment: Voted to reopen because this issue seems not to be related to a question ban.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I'm seeing a "proceed" button there, Safari 10 on MacOS. Have you tried with a different browser?

Comment: I'm seeing "proceed" using chrome.

Comment: The button should be there whenever you use javascript or not.

Comment: What happens if you try click the Ask Question button while logged out or using a different browser?

Comment: I can see the "proceed" in Safari 9.1.2 as well.

Comment: All simile  for FireFox 32.0.3 on Mac I can't seeing   "proceed" button also but can to  get post form url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask                                                       Braiam javascript enabled all time.

Comment: Robert Columbia At first this post was closed with appellation  to not relevant to my case. I only repost it like not connected to my problem. That is all. Reading with attention  -- it link not help in my case. I not get any of this messages .....